# Moving MS Excel data to a website via a web service

Tags: web-services, excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet template with data and a chart. I want to be able to publish (repeatably) the raw data to a web server using using a web service interface. I would like to do this with vanilla Excel--no add-ons or required ActiveX controls, etc.

I am open to suggestions on the web service technology: REST, etc.

Are there any built-in apis that do this? Could someone point me to the docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussing the subject with a Microsoft developer evangelist (J Sawyer) I believe the best approach would be to use VSTO (Visual Studio Tools for Office). I would create a clickonce assembly that would interface directly with the Excel template, read the Excel data and push the data to a web service.

There doesn't seem to be any mechanism using just vanilla Excel and VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use the OLEDB driver and read the data from Excel directly. 
(This would not read the chart image, though).

[Example](http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/srcview.aspx?dir=MSOffice&file=adonet-excel.cs).

Then you can expose that in any way you see fit.  REST would be fine.

Comment: Actually I was looking for a way to connect to a web service from inside of an Excel template. I'm currently looking at using Visual Studio Tools for Office to allow a dotnet assembly from inside the spreadsheet. The dotnet code can then read the spreadsheet and talk to the web server.

Comment: Oh!  Sorry, I misunderstood.  Yes, VSTO will help you build what you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft provides the ability to do this with Microsoft Excel Services - which are part of Office SharePoint Server.

[SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) can be used in various ways to take advantage of Excel workbooks from ASP.NET (aspx pages or web services).

See the [live ASP.NET samples](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/) which show how to generate Excel workbooks, generate images / dashboards from Excel charts and ranges, do Excel compatible calculations, etc...

You can download a free evaluation [here](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/downloads/register.aspx).

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm not sure I want to use sharepoint though. I really want to use a vanilla ASP.NET website. I'm  considering using VSTO to write code to read the spreadsheet and send the data to the web service. See the above comment.